# How to check the values of an array and delete some properties based on the condition?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

i have an array like this :`PermissionList:["RealPersonTab","LegalPersonTab","CustomerUserTab" ,...]`
.And I have another array like this :

```
customerSubMenu: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "RealPerson",
          to: "/main/customers/real",
          accessKey:"RealPersonTab"
        },
        {
          id: 1.1,
          name: "LegalPerson",
          to: "/main/customers/legal",
          accessKey:"LegalPersonTab"
        },
        {
          id: 1.2,
          name: "CustomerUser",
          to: "/main/users/customer",
          accessKey:"CustomerUserTab"
        },
        {
          id: 1.3,
          name: "OfficeUser",
          to: "/main/users/official",
          accessKey:"OfficeUserTab"
        },   
      ],
```

This is how I use **customerSubMenu**:

```
   {customerSubMenu.map((link) => {
                        return (
                          <div key={link.id}>
                            <ul className="space">
                              <li onClick={() => this.handleClick(link.id) } className="sidebar-item">
                                <Link to={link.to}>
                                  <i className="sidebar-icon"></i>
                                    <span>
                                      {link.name}
                                    </span>
                                </Link>
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        );
                      })}
                    </div>
                  ) :("")}
```

What I want is if, for example, **RealPersonTab** did not exist in the **PermissionList** array,In the **customerSubMenu** array, delete the object whose **accessKey** was equal to **RealPersonTab**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to filter the `customerSubMenu` before mapping it to JSX.

Filter the `customerSubMenu` array by elements that have an `accessKey` property in the `customerSubMenu` array.

```
customerSubMenu
  .filter(link => customerSubMenu.includes(link.accessKey))
  .map(link => { ..... JSX ......})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just update the array of `customerSubMenu` to be equal to and altered version which return only item which `accessKey` exists in the `PermissionList`. You can perform that like this

```
customerSubMenu = [...customerSubMenu].filter((menu) => {
    return PermissionList.indexOf(menu.accessKey) !== -1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

### Solution using `Set`

```js
const 
  permissionList = new Set(["RealPersonTab", "LegalPersonTab", "CustomerUserTab"]),
  customerSubMenu = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "RealPerson",
      to: "/main/customers/real",
      accessKey: "RealPersonTab",
    },
    {
      id: 1.1,
      name: "LegalPerson",
      to: "/main/customers/legal",
      accessKey: "LegalPersonTab",
    },
    {
      id: 1.2,
      name: "CustomerUser",
      to: "/main/users/customer",
      accessKey: "CustomerUserTab",
    },
    {
      id: 1.3,
      name: "OfficeUser",
      to: "/main/users/official",
      accessKey: "OfficeUserTab",
    },
  ];
  filteredMenu = customerSubMenu.filter((c) => permissionList.has(c.accessKey));

console.log(filteredMenu)
```